# session not carrying between the pages

Tags: php, html, json, forms, session

i have created a login page here is the code ,i am not using any database and i am supposed to carry the email of the logged in user until it loggs out ,here is my login page(login.php) . 
In the form action i have called a web service with some keys ,i have convereted it into json format and then on sending to server i get a response in json format which is decoded and after checking some condition(all these are happening in profile.php) they are redirected to another page based on the response of the condition check the page to which it is redirected is (pipm.php).

login.php is

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>LOGIN FOR PRODUCT MANAGEMENT</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="contact">
    <form id="myForm1" action="profile.php" method="post">
    <div style="margin-left:180px;color:#445668">
    <h3>LOGIN</h3></div> 
    <p>
    <div style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;">
    <label for="username">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <input type="email" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username"/>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;">
    <label for="password">Password</label></div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password"/>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:-30px;width: 185px;text-align: right; font-size: 12px; color: #445668; 
    text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;"><a href="forgotpass.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Forgot Password?</label></a>
                <div style="margin-left:440px;margin-top:-20px;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send "/></div>
     </p>
     </form>
     </div>


<?php
$temp=$_SESSION['username'];
echo "$temp";
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
 $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
 } 
?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

profile.php is

```
<?php
session_start();
$usernamepm = $_POST['username'];
$passwordpm =$_POST['password'];
$loginpm=array(
'user_name'=> "$usernamepm" ,
'password' => "$passwordpm"
);
$url='http://192.168.2.31:8080/Product_Deployment/services/user/login';
        $data="$loginpm";
        $ch=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($loginpm));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
        $response=  curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $jsondepm = "$response";
        $jsonde_o= json_decode($jsondepm);
        $jsonde_a=json_decode($jsondepm,true);
        $loginstatus=$jsonde_a[firsttimelogin];
        if($loginstatus=="yes")
        {  
        header("Location:pipm.php");
        }
        if($loginstatus=="no") 
        {
        header("Location:pipm.php");
        }
        if($loginstatus=="")
        {
        header("Location:login.php");
        }


?>
```

pipm.php is

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head><title>PERSONAL INFO COLLECTION PAGE</title>
<link href="pipm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
   function onKeyPressBlockNumbers(e)
{
    var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    reg = /\d/;
    return !reg.test(keychar);
}
 function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }   
$(function() { 
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});

    function validate()
{
    var vfname=trim(document.frm.fname.value);
    var vlname=trim(document.frm.lname.value);
    var vdatepicker1=trim(document.frm.datepicker1.value);
    var vmobile=trim(document.frm.mobile.value);
    var vaddressline1=trim(document.frm.addressline1.value);
    var vaddressline2=trim(document.frm.addressline2.value);
    var vaddressline3=trim(document.frm.addressline3.value);
    var vcountry=trim(document.frm.country.value);
    var vstate=trim(document.frm.state.value);
    var vcity=trim(document.frm.city.value);
    var vpin=trim(document.frm.pin.value);
    var vcompanyname=trim(document.frm.companyname.value);
    var vwebsite=trim(document.frm.website.value);
    var vcompanyemail=trim(document.frm.companyemail.value);
    var vphoneno=trim(document.frm.phoneno.value);
    var vcaddressline1=trim(document.frm.caddressline1.value);
    var vcaddressline2=trim(document.frm.caddressline2.value);
    var vcaddressline3=trim(document.frm.caddressline3.value);
    var vcountry1=trim(document.frm.country1.value);
    var vstate1=trim(document.frm.state1.value);
    var vcity1=trim(document.frm.city1.value);
    var vpin1=trim(document.frm.pin1.value);


      if(vfname=="")
    {
        alert("Fisrt Name Field is Empty");
        document.frm.fname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(vlname=="")
    {
        alert("Last Name Field is Empty");
        document.frm.lname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(vdatepicker1=="")
    {
        alert("DOB Field is Empty");
        document.frm.datepicker1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(vmobile=="")
    {
        alert("Mobile Number Field is Empty");
        document.frm.mobile.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vaddressline1=="")
   {
        alert("Address Line1 Field is Empty");
        document.frm.addressline1.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vaddressline2=="")
   {
        alert("Address Line2 Field is Empty");
        document.frm.addressline2.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vaddressline3=="")
   {
        alert("Address Line3 Field is Empty");
        document.frm.addressline3.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vcountry=="")
   {
        alert("Country Field is Empty");
        document.frm.country.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vstate=="")
   {
        alert("State Field is Empty");
        document.frm.state.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vcity=="")
   {
        alert("City Field is Empty");
        document.frm.city.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vpin=="")
   {
        alert("Pin Address Field is Empty");
        document.frm.pin.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vcompanyname=="")
   {
        alert("Company Name Field is Empty");
        document.frm.companyname.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vwebsite=="")
   {
        alert("Website Field is Empty");
        document.frm.website.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vcompanyemail=="")
   {
        alert("Email Field is Empty");
        document.frm.companyemail.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vphoneno=="")
   {
        alert("Phone Number Field is Empty");
        document.frm.phoneno.focus();
        return false;
   }
   else if(vcaddressline1=="")
   {
        alert("Address Line 1 Field is Empty");
        document.frm.caddressline1.focus();
        return false;
   }
  else if(vcaddressline2=="")
  {
       alert("Address Line 2 Field is Empty");
       document.frm.caddressline2.focus();
       return false;
  }
  else if(vcaddressline3=="")
  {
       alert("Address Line 3 Field is Empty");
       document.frm.caddressline3.focus();
       return false;
  }
  else if(vcountry1=="")
  {
       alert("Country Field is Empty");
       document.frm.country1.focus();
       return false;
  }
  else if(vstate1=="")
  {
       alert("State Field is Empty");
       document.frm.state1.focus();
       return false;
  }
  else if(vcity1=="")
  {
      alert("City Field is Empty");
      document.frm.city1.focus();
      return false;
  }
  else if(vpin1=="")
  {
      alert("Pin Address Field is Empty");
      document.frm.pin1.focus();
      return false;
  }

}

function trim(s) {
    return s.replace( /^\s*/, "" ).replace( /\s*$/, "" );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="contact">
    <form id="personalinfo" name="frm" action="home.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validate();">
        <h1>PERSONAL INFORMATION</h1>
       <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstname" placeholder="enter your firstname" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" ></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lastname" placeholder="enter your last name" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" ></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker" placeholder="Enter your date of Birth"/></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="number" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="enter your mobile number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" name="addressline1" id="addressline1" placeholder="enter your addressline 1" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" ></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" name="addressline2" id="addressline2" placeholder="enter your addressline 2" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" ></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" name="addressline3" id="addressline3" placeholder="enter your addressline 3" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" ></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="enter your country" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" ></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="enter your state" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" ></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="enter your city" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" ></div>
        <div style="margin-left:50px">
        <input type="text" name="pin" id="pin" placeholder="enter your pin address" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></div>

    <div style="margin-left:500px;margin-top:-550px;"> 
        <div style="margin-left:-122px;margin-top:-400px;"></div>
        <input type="text" name="comapnyname" id="companyname" placeholder="enter your company name" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" >
        <input type="text" name="website" id="website" placeholder="enter your company website" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" >
        <input type="email" name="companyemail" id="companyemail" placeholder="enter your company email">
        <input type="number" name="phoneno" id="phoneno" placeholder="enter your phone number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
        <input type="text" name="caddressline1" id="caddressline1" placeholder="enter your addressline 1" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" >
        <input type="text" name="caddressline2" id="caddressline2" placeholder="enter your addressline 2" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" >
        <input type="text" name="caddressline3" id="caddressline3" placeholder="enter your addressline 3" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" >
        <input type="text" name="country1" id="country1" placeholder="enter your country" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" >
        <input type="text" name="state1" id="state1" placeholder="enter your state" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" >
        <input type="text" name="city1" id="city1" placeholder="enter your city" onkeypress="return onKeyPressBlockNumbers(event);" >
        <input type="number" name="pin1" id="pin1" placeholder="enter your pin address" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
        </div>

        <div style="margin-left:-1000px"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="SAVE"/></div>
               </form>
  </div>
 HI <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>

</body>
</html>
```

i am really confused on what i am doing wrong,please correct me
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` on all pages?

Comment: pipm.php is in http://pastebin.com/DnM3zcCd as i have less than 10 reputation i cant paste more than 2 links so here is the code for pipm.php.Thank you

Comment: yes sir,i am calling session_start on all pages

Comment: What do you get if you **var_dump** *$_SESSION* on each page?

Comment: I don't see where you store the `$_session` vars. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your login page is submitting to profile.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `login.php` the form action is going to `profile.php` as such:

```
<form id="myForm1" action="profile.php" method="post">
```

In `profile.php` you're not setting any `$_SESSION` variables. You need to move these lines that are currently in `login.php` to the top of `profile.php`:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you SeanWM,works like a charm,i have one question why i cant put that niche of code in login.php ?why it is in profile.php?

Comment: ok i got the answer for the question i have asked as the form action is taking place in profile.php it is written there .Thank you